# How to simulate iid random variables from my own cdf?

Tags: r

So, I have a cdf, given by

```
F=function(x){
  if (x < (pi/2) & x > -(pi/2)){
    q <- (sin(x)+1)/2
  } else {
    q <- 0
  }
  return(q)
}
```

And I want to simulate 1000 iid RV's with this cdf--how do I do this?

Comment: The cdf itself is pretty useless. You have to compute the inverse of `F` and apply it to a uniform variable.

Comment: It's not a CDF - F(Inf) != 1

Comment: lim(x-->pi/2)F=1, though.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a cdf, you simply invert the function. That would be:

```
F(x) = (sin(x) + 1) / 2
2*F(x) -1 = sin(x)
sin^-1(2*F(x) -1) = x

# in R code
Finv = function(p) {
  x = 180/pi * asin(2*p - 1)
  ind = abs(x) < (2/pi)
  x[ind] = 0
  return(x)
}
```

Now we have an expression for the inverse cdf. Next if we simply input random values between 0 and 1 for p we can pseudo randomly sample from f(x). This method is known as [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). To show it works:

```
Finv = function(p) {
  x = 180/pi * asin(2*p - 1) # invere F
  ind = abs(x) < (2/pi) # which fall in range pi/2
  x = x[ind] # save only those that fall in range of pi/2
  return(x)
}
p = runif(1e6)
x = Finv(p)
hist(x, breaks = 50, freq = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks--I'd forgotten about this method.